# .htaccess URL rewrite after migrating from Wordpress to Expression Engine

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, expressionengine

I'm helping a client move their blog from a separate Wordpress installation to part of the overall Expression Engine installation for their new (and very large!) website.

The old url structure for the blog was `www.site.com/blog/yyyy/mm/foo-bar-title`

The new URL structure will be `www.site.com/blog/article/foo-bar-title`

The .htaccess file isn't that complex so far, essentially it's this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And try as I might I can't seem to find a rewrite method that gets the URL rewritten with a 301 redirect without causing an infinite loop.

So far I have `RewriteRule ^(.*)\[0-9]+/[0-9]+/?$ /blog/article/ [R=301]` but that causes the infinite loop. I've looked at the other questions and answers, but they all seem to deal with just Wordpress (when you search for wordpress), although strictly speaking this won't involve wordpress at all and just Expression Engine.

All help very much appreciated!

Comment: If your question doesn't get the attention you need here, consider posting it in http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You may find it helpful to turn on Apache Server's rewrite log while you tinker with this.

I think you are looking for something like this:

> RewriteRule ^index.php/blog/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /blog/article/$1 [R=301]